# Authorize ASP.NET Core Web API controller based on Google Access Token from React

Tags: reactjs, jwt, google-oauth, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to secure my API endpoints by allowing only users who have previously logged in using Google on my React front-end to send a request (GET/POST...) to one of my controllers.

Right now I am getting a generated token through GoogleLogin from `@react-oauth/google` package and I'm trying to provide it to my backend to authorize endpoints. I've never done any sort of authorization before so I'm not sure how I can register a service for verifying my token (no code, as I'm really not doing anything on the backend).